# How to Get Git History After forced update on both master and branch

Tags: git, github

I was working on a master branch and l used `git add -u` because there were deleted files in the branch l didn't want.

After l committed and pushed using `-f` to remote. Now my local changes has overridden the master branch since the last checkout of master.

Please l need help.

Comment: `git push -f` implies "force push"; that is, Git trusts that you know what you're doing.  Do you know of anyone that has a copy of this repo on their machine that hasn't pulled/rectified the conflicts?

Comment: @Makoto I have a local back up on my machine, how do l restore to previous master history?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly whats the `-f` does.

Its forcing the push which will overwrite any data on the server.

## How to restore previous commits

- If you are using github [read here how to recover it](http://pablofabregat.com/git/yes-you-can-revert-a-git-push-force/)
- #### Check to see if you have the data on your machine

  If you do have the data and you know what was the last commit you can checkout it out and push again at this point.
- **Important notice** git never throw away data unless `gc` was executed. so even if you don't see this commit its still in your local repository you just have to find it.
  You can find it by executing `git fsck` which will "find" all the commits that are not reachable at this moment. Now you simply have to find teh right one and check it out
- Write script that execute `git cat-file -t` on your objects folder and find out all the tree objects which represents commit.
  Once you find them print the out with the content with `git cat-file -p <commitid>` and find the one you are looking for.
- use `git reflog` on the server if you have access to it.
  `git reflog`is **local history** only so running it on any other machine will not work.
- #### On your local machine

  ```
  # work on local master
  git checkout <branch name>

  # reset to the previous state of origin/master, as recorded by reflog
  git reset --hard origin/<branch name>@{1}

  # If this is the commit that yo need rest hard to this commit 
  # git reset --hard <commit id>

  # if not try to loop over the reflog until you will find the commit you need

  # finally, push the branch back as you did before
  git push -f origin <branch name>
  ```
- Check to see if any other team member still has the "old content" of your branch

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access to the server that is hosting your git repository, you can use `git reflog` to search for lost commits.  You'll have to inspect the hashes that `git reflog` produces in order to find out which ones were on the master branch before your forced push.  Once you find the lost commits, I'd recommend using `git checkout <hash> -b lostbranch` on the latest commit to put the lost commits all into a branch, then merge that branch into master.

Comment: Thanks. I have used reflog and then used "git reset --hard <Head of previous local branch>", now l am on the previous commit before the force push to master. How do l restore my team member's remote history on master since l last checked out master?

Comment: If the commits don't show up in the `git reflog` then your team members probably didn't push any commits.  To be sure, double check the commits in `git reflog` and make sure no commits have the last "head of previous local branch" as parent

Comment: note:  you won't see your team members missing commits in your local tree.  You will only be able to find their lost commits if you shell into the server and run `git reflog` there

Comment: reflog only shows my branch's head activities, l do not see my team member's head activities. But l can also see "checkout:moving from master to my_branch". How do l reset the remote master to previous history before l did the local and remote override with -f ?

Comment: If you're doing this on your local machine, you will only see your own activity.  Are you shelled into the server or doing this local?